# How to test a Resource controller with unit test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, react-admin

I have the following standard react-admin structure set–up and everything works as expected, the resource gets the data from the endpoints for `GET_LIST` and `GET_ONE` the issue I have is I want to test the `CandidateView` component and I do not know how to pass it some mocked data to check when rendered it will contain all the data expected.

```
<Admin
    title="Admin"
    dashboard={Home}
    dataProvider={restProvider}
    history={history}
    loginPage={Login}
    menu={Menu}
  >
    <Resource
      name="candidates"
      list={Candidates}
      icon={UserIcon}
      edit={CandidateEdit}
      show={CandidateView}
    />
  </Admin>
```

Do I have to mount the Resource to be able to test this or is there a better way in which I can just mount and test the subcomponents that I'm interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, React Admin controllers are designed to be easy to use and hack with, not easy to test.

Assuming that you are using a simple show view like this one:

```
export const CandidateView = props => (
    <Show {...props}>
        <SimpleShowLayout>
            <TextField source="title" />
            <TextField source="position" />
            <RichTextField source="body" />
            <DateField label="Registration date" source="created_at" />
        </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Show>
);
```

Indeed, you can read the source code, find all the HOCs, inject all the required props, mounting the view and test the output. It's painful, but doable.

But if your only goal is just to test that this view has the correct fields that are `title`, `position`, `body` and `created_at`, it isn't an efficient way to do it.

We see the React Admin resource declaration as a simple configuration. (you won't test XML files)

On our apps, **we use end-to-end tests to check that all views are well configured and have the right components and behaviors**.

You can find an example of E2E tests with [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) or selenium for that page on React Admin itself.
Take a look in [`cypress/integration`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/cypress/integration) folder to see all the tests we run.