# How to test component view in React-Admin using <TestContext>?

Tags: testing, react-admin

I am wondering how to use `<TestContext>` as a sufficient tool for **testing react-admin custom components view**. So far we have not encountered an error rendering basic HTML element inside `<TestContext>`, but with RA component test are failing mostly due to:

```
TypeError: Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target or handler
```

In our case, we do not have a redux store connected to our component and for now, just want to test the display with simple props using an example from [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/UnitTesting.html#testing-custom-views).

```
describe('<EditManufacturer/>', () => {
  let testUtils: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockEditManufacturerProps = {
      basePath: '/',
      id: '123',
      resource: 'foo',
    };

    testUtils = render(
    <TestContext>
      <EditManufacturer {...mockEditManufacturerProps}/>
    </TestContext>)
  });


  // test

  })
});
```

Example syntax above produces another error:

```
Cannot read property '{"type":"GET_ONE","resource":"foo","payload":{"id":"123"}}' of undefined
```

Here is our `EditManufacturer.tsx` component:

```
const EditManufacturer:React.FC<EditProps> = props => {
  return(
    <Edit {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ManufacturerInputFields/>
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>

  )};

export default EditManufacturer;
```

Is injecting all the required props for HOCs and then mounting the view as mentioned in answer [here](http://https:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897935/how-to-test-a-resource-controller-with-unit-test) or using e2e tests the only solution? Any help would be appreciated.